# ui:iterate render another ui:iterate

Tags: ajax, jsf, selectonemenu, uirepeat

I have very basic question on jsf/ajax.

I would like to render second ui:iterate and h:selectoneMenu based on values in first ui:iterate.

My code is like below.

```
<tr><th >
Vehicle Usage:</th>
<ui:repeat id="usageId" var="veh" value="#{vehicle}"  varStatus="myVarStatus">
    <th>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="mvVehUse" value="#{veh.mvVehUse}" >
        <f:selectItems itemLabel="#{entry[1]}" itemValue="#{entry[0]}" value="#{listFrmDB}" var="entry"/>
         <f:ajax  event="change" execute="@this" render=":vehicleForm:buReleated"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    </th>
</ui:repeat>
</tr>



<tr>
<th >
Business Use of Vehicle:
</th> 
<h:panelGroup  id="buReleated">
<ui:repeat id="businessUse" var="veh" value="#{vehicle}" >
 <th>
<h:selectOneMenu id="typeBusUse" value="#{veh.typeBusUse}" disabled="#{veh.mvVehUse != 'B'}">
 <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="" />
 <f:selectItems itemLabel="#{entry[1]}" itemValue="#{entry[0]}" value="#{2ndListFromDB}" var="entry"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
</th>
</ui:repeat>
</h:panelGroup>
</tr>
```

I would like to render typeBusUse based on mvvehuse for each of Veh. and I want to use two different iterates as shown above.
Can we render buRelated panel based on mvVehUse ajax call. Could you please some one guide me on this.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: And the actual problem is? ('does not work' is not the right answer)